# Merge 'photo' into 'photography'

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tag-merge

Just encountered this couple:

- [photography](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/photography) (× 57) already has a tag wiki excerpt
- [photo](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/photo) (× 8) has no excerpt and no tag wiki either

As commonly "photo" is just an abbreviation of "photography", and the tag excerpt of the latter fully matches the former, the two should be merged with [photography](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/photography) being the master.

Though it might sound stupid on first sight, we still should consider keeping [photo](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/photo) as synonym: while "photography" would still turn up when typing "photo", some people might simply type "photo" and hit the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key – which is how that tag might have been created in the first place.

Comment: I agree with this, if there's support for it I would do it.

Comment: @Undo with "support" you mean "consense" – or "help"? I could simply re-tag those 8 questions ("help") if it's that #D

Comment: I mean consensus, we can merge them fairly easily once we can all agree on what needs to be done :)

Comment: @Undo A little click for a mod, a bunch of clicks for a high-rep, heh? Yeah, full ack :D Start with upvoting? #D Or shall I post a related answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Merged [photo](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/photo) into [photography](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/photography), and created a synonym.

Answer (score 3):

Yes that should totally be done.

Answer (score 2):

I noticed that too, and my initial thought was to merge them.

But then I realized that many people use "photo" or "photograph" to mean the result of a camera, but "photography" to mean the process of using a camera.

Software that edits/organizes/adjusts/filters photos is very different than software that records/takes photographs.

*Having tags that reflect these differences is important.*

Perhaps "photograph" can be a synonym of "image", "photograph-editor" could be created as a synonym of "image-editor", and "photograph-processor" could be a synonym of "image-processor" (currently called "image-processing", but that's another discussion).  That would give those types of Q/A a happy home.

It would then follow that "photography" could be used for taking pictures, and perhaps "video-recording" could be used for recording videos (aka motion pictures).

Now the trick will be if someone wants to apply a photographic filter to an image.  Their inclination would probably be to tag it under "photography".  The best place would probably by "image-processor", but it will take some effort to get people to use that system.

Another solution would be for "photography" to be a modifier tag; thus, one would tag a photographic filter as "image-processor" and "photography".  That dilutes to power of "photography" a bit, but is more likely to be accepted and used.

Comment: That's a good point. The current usage of [tag:photo] vs [tag:photography] doesn't reflect any such distinction though: I can't see any difference in their usage. But some of the [tag:photography]/[tag:photo] questions should probably be retagged to one of the [tag:image*] tags.

Comment: Yes, very true.  I think that coming up with distinctive tag names can help (but it won't be foolproof).  As it is right now, I can understand why users would use photo and photography interchangeably.  I think SE has some way to direct users to the corrects tags.